# Complex Conjugate of Polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I'm trying to calculate the conjugate of $p(x) = 1+x+x^2$, $p \in P_2(\mathbb{C})$ to use in a question regarding inner product spaces and I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Is it something to do with $\overline{p(x)} = p(\overline{x})$? Even if that's what I'm supposed to use I don't see how I can use that in any way when all the coefficients are real numbers.

Comment: Hint: Look at the factors of $p(x)$.

Comment: Wouldnt $\overline{p(x)} = p(x)$ then since there are no imaginary parts to conjugate?

Comment: @Shansss you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean simply the complex conjugate of the polynomial, then, being $p(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$, you have $\overline{p(x)}=p(x)$ like any real number.

Comment: Only for $x$ real and any other arguments where $p$ is real.  Else you need $p(\overline{x})$.

Comment: Well it depends on the context, I guess. $p(\overline{x})$ is not a polynomial  - strictly speaking. The ring of polynomials can be seen as generated by the ring (field in this case) and a new variable with no relations.

Answer (score 1):

The map $z\mapsto\overline{z}$ is a ring homomorfism, then it preserves addition and multiplication.
In that way, given a polynomial
$$p(z) = a_0 + a_1 z + \cdots + a_nz^n, $$
it is true that
$$\overline{p(z)} = \overline{a_0} + \overline{a_1}\overline{z} + \cdots + \overline{a_n}\overline{z}^n.$$
Then, if $a_i\in\mathbb R$ for all $i=1,\cdots,n$, it follows that
$$\overline{p(z)} = a_0 + a_1\overline{z} + \cdots + a_n\overline{z}^n = p(\overline{z}).$$